# Cannot resolve symbol PermissionListener in react-native-image-picker

Tags: react-native

import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionListener;

Cannot resolve symbol PermissionListener.

friends i am a newbie in react-native and getting this issue in react-native-image-picker. i have added api 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1' in my gradle file.
any solution friends?

Comment: plz mention which library are you using? write  what you have done?

Comment: have you write  'react-native link'